# How do you copy and paste into a large list with many items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I saw several articles like this one that describe how you copy and paste from Excel into a worksheet view or a list in quick edit mode.

[3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/)

the problem with this is you can only paste into the blank cell at the bottom. if you highlight the first cell and attempt to copy over what's already in the list, it gives you this error:

> The information cannot be pasted because the paste area is not completely within the grid.  Paste into a different cell or try inserting more columns and or rows into the grid

How do you bulk paste (like a thousand rows from Excel) into a list, and paste over all the existing list values that are already there? Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Can you step back and explain the bigger picture? Why would you manually copy and paste thousands of items into a SharePoint list, overwriting existing items? What is the business need? Maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: I need to refresh my list on a weekly basis. the source of the list comes from a database that has data that is updated frequently. so there is need to keep the list refreshed as well. I just don't know what's a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the existing records by copy & paste action in SharePoint list, make sure you do not exceed the current number of cells in the list.

The error message suggests that the contents you plan to paste cannot fit in the cells and need additional spaces.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: thanks Chelsea, do you have any suggestion on how to paste over a larger list that extends across several pages? like a way other than pasting page by page? thanks.

Comment: @edtopia Consider using PowerShell to copy contents from Excel to SP list: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-import-excel-to-existing-list-using-powershell.html / And another sample with explanation here: https://practical365.com/sharepoint-online/csv-file-to-sharepoint/

Comment: thanks Chelsea, will try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can import Excel rows (over 10K)  into SharePoint custom list using Power Automate. Read the following article -

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/flow-import-excel-online-rows-into-sharepoint-custom-list/m-p/572280/highlight/true#M2359